# numpy pad array with nan, getting strange float instead

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to pad an array with `np.nan`

```
import numpy as np
print np.version.version
# 1.10.2
combine = lambda real, theo: np.vstack((theo, np.pad(real, (0, theo.shape[0] - real.shape[0]), 'constant', constant_values=np.nan)))
real = np.arange(20)
theoretical = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
result = combine(real, theoretical)
np.any(np.isnan(result))
# False
```

Inspecting `result`, it seems instead of `np.nan`, the array is getting padded with `-9.22337204e+18`. What's going on here? How can I get `np.nan`?

Comment: Try `real = np.arange(20, dtype=float)`.

Comment: Look at the result produced by `np.pad(real, (0, theo.shape[0] - real.shape[0]), 'constant', constant_values=np.nan)` when `real` is an *integer* array.

Comment: Thanks - forgot `real` was an integer array. Why does this behaviour happen with integers?

Comment: `np.nan` is a float.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result of `pad` has the same type as the input.  `np.nan` is a float

```
In [874]: np.pad(np.ones(2,dtype=int),1,mode='constant',constant_values=(np.nan,))
Out[874]: array([-2147483648,           1,           1, -2147483648])

In [875]: np.pad(np.ones(2,dtype=float),1,mode='constant',constant_values=(np.nan,))
Out[875]: array([ nan,   1.,   1.,  nan])
```

The int pad is `np.nan` cast as an integer:

```
In [878]: np.array(np.nan).astype(int)
Out[878]: array(-2147483648)
```

Comment: Is there an integer version of `np.nan`?

Comment: Masked arrays use `999999` as the default `fill_value`, but values like that don't propagate through calculations in the same way that `np.nan` does.  Talk about `nan` often references `IEEE-754` floating point standard.