# How to append values to multidimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I efficiently append values to a multidimensional numpy array?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print(a)
```

I want to append `np.NaN` for `k=2` times to each dimension/array of the outer array?

One option would be to use a loop - but I guess there must be something smarter (vectorized) in numpy

Expected result would be:

```
np.array([[1,2,3, np.NaN, np.NaN, ], [4,5,6, np.NaN, np.NaN, ]])
```

I.e. I am looking for a way to:

```
np.concatenate((a, np.NaN))
```

on all the inner dimensions.

A

```
np.append(a,  [[np.NaN, np.NaN]], axis=0)
```

fails with:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 2
```

Comment: With `axis` `np.append` is just a call to `np.concatenate`, as indicated by the traceback.  You are trying to join a (2,3) and (1,2) on the first dimension.  But the target is a (2,5), so you need to add a (2,2) on axis 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem [np.hstack()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) or [np.pad()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) should do the job.

**Using np.hstack():**

```
k = 2
a_mat = np.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6]])
nan_mat = np.zeros((a_mat.shape[0], k))
nan_mat.fill(np.nan)

a_mat = np.hstack((a_mat, nan_mat))
```

**Using np.pad():**

```
k = 2
padding_shape = [(0, 0), (0, k)]   # [(dim1_before_pads, dim1_after_pads)..]
a_mat = np.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6]])
np.pad(a_mat, mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan)
```

Note: Incase you are using np.pad() for filling with np.nan, check this post out as well: [about padding with np.nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514976/numpy-pad-array-with-nan-getting-strange-float-instead/35515486#35515486)